# keep Mega dropdown menu element active without hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, megamenu

Here is the menu link :- 
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/
I'm making a drop-down list on that menu and when the list goes out of the menu-dropdown area it closes .I know we might need a little bit of jquery but i'm unable to do it.I tried this but its not working :-

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().hover();
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide an example of the code you've created so far

Comment: do you want to trigger the hover event?

Comment: Ah well ..  i have a dropdown in the submenu and a submit button whenever i select the dropdowns element  the submenu closes. So onchange of dropdown  i want to fire an event that keep it open even if the cursor is not pointing the sub-menu,as a user is needed to click the button to submit.It closes before submitting.

Comment: @undefined Yeah .. Something of that kind

Comment: your can trigger the hover by using `trigger('hover')`

Comment: I used an alternative of doing it.Instead of dropdown i used MultiSelect Dropdown Control. In that way it wasn't going outside the area of dropdown menu.